# AutoMapper with IList<Item>

Tags: automapper

I have Article class with property

```
private IList<Tag> _tags;
public virtual IList<Tag> Tags
{
get{
if(_tags == null)
  _tags = TagService.GetTags(this);
return _tags;
}
}
```

Since there is no SET for Tags automapper will not set tags when mapping from viewmodel to view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the UseDestinationValue option:

ForMember(dest => dest.Tags, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());

In the latest DLL on the trunk, AutoMapper should pick up readonly list-type members.

Answer (score 0):

You can Ignore then property using:

```
ForMember(dest => dest.Tags, opt => opt.Ignore());
```